# Sort array in PHP by value and maintain index association

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$array = array(
    'john' => 2,
    'adam' => 3,
    'ben' => 10,
    'tim' => 1
);
```

I have tried all sorts of functions with PHP to achieve this array structure:

```
$array = array(
    'tim' => 1,
    'john' => 2,
    'adam' => 3,
    'ben' => 10
);
```

Where its ordered by the array values and the key/values maintained. Any ideas?

Comment: PHP `asort` function do the trick : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work using [asort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php):

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'john' => 2,
    'adam' => 3,
    'ben' => 10,
    'tim' => 1,
);
asort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
print_r($array);
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [tim] => 1
    [john] => 2
    [adam] => 3
    [ben] => 10
)
```

Checkout [the demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xACwbO).

Comment: Can you show me the output please because I am getting different results!

Answer (score -1):

perhaps you are looking for [asort() — Sort an array and maintain index association](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).

Comment: Please provide some detail in you answer rather than just a link.