# How to get the keys with highest values in a php array

Tags: php

I have this array...

```
Array (
[1168] => 46
[6973] => 27
[4585] => 24
[1224] => 23
[2010] => 20
[7514] => 19
[1167] => 17
[8349] => 7
[2476] => 7
[5313] => 7
[1208] => 2
)
```

And I need to get three keys (as values) with the highest values in the previous array:

```
Array (
[0] => 1168
[1] => 6973
[2] => 4585
)
```

Comment: It's not possible to iterate an array without loops. Think about it for a moment.

Comment: Is this [tag:homework]? If it is, please use the tag [tag:homework]. It won't stop SO folks from providing an answer, but instead they will try and give you more insightful answers.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898822/sort-array-in-php-by-value-and-maintain-index-association and close but not quite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720096/php-get-the-first-n-elements-of-an-array. Also have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: minitech, I think a can do this in Java or Ruby using Hashmaps or Hashes, respectively. I'm just wondering if that's possible in PHP.

Comment: This isn't the best question ever, but I don't think it deserves -7 votes for being over-simplistic (yes, I was disappointed with the "game" too) but +1 to counter-act.

Comment: @Fernando Á.: It is possible... Haven't you checked my answer yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the array always sorted in descending order? If not, you need to `arsort($arr)` it first:

```
$highest_keys = array_keys(array_slice($arr, 0, 3));
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already edited the question name, a bit late though

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

```
$a = array('foo' => 3, 'bar' => 2, 'fuz' => 1, 'baz' => 0);
$k = array_keys(array_slice($a, 0, 3));
print_r($k);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/gOGSa0BL)

Comment: Not the keys are sorted, but the values.

Comment: Well, my array was already sorted. Beside of the sort($k) the rest works perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @FelixKling I missed the world `highest values`. I thought is was the highest keys that he want. I updated the code accordingly =)