# PHP sorting table

Tags: php, arrays

Simple functions like  [PHP_SORT](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) doesn't work, also tips from comments couldn't help me enough.
I'm trying to sort my table by int values but I can't manage it. This is sample of my table.

```
array(3) {
 ["normal"]=>
 array(20) {
[58]=>
int(7343)
[33]=>
int(7032)
[34]=>
int(7322)
[65]=>
int(7017)
[60]=>
int(6996)
[62]=>
int(7022)
[35]=>
int(6508)
[56]=>
int(7323)
[61]=>
int(413)
[57]=>
int(7327)
[67]=>
int(7001)
[72]=>
int(6469)
[64]=>
int(5297)
[59]=>
int(5135)
[71]=>
int(5322)
[70]=>
int(5452)
[69]=>
int(6556)
[68]=>
int(6436)
[66]=>
int(6840)
[48]=>
int(6862)
 }
 ["high"]=>
array(19) {
[58]=>
int(2717)
[60]=>
int(2562)
[33]=>
int(2718)
[34]=>
int(2722)
[61]=>
int(1964)
[64]=>
int(2337)
[65]=>
int(368)
[67]=>
int(2308)
[72]=>
int(1880)
[59]=>
int(2202)
[57]=>
int(2587)
[56]=>
int(1474)
[62]=>
int(2416)
[48]=>
int(2455)
[35]=>
int(2356)
[69]=>
int(1910)
[71]=>
int(2229)
[68]=>
int(2293)
[63]=>
int(2582)
 }
  ["low"]=>
 array(12) {
[58]=>
int(1905)
[48]=>
int(1771)
[60]=>
int(1842)
[56]=>
int(1179)
[57]=>
int(1714)
[64]=>
int(1243)
[34]=>
int(1903)
[63]=>
int(57)
[59]=>
int(1837)
[35]=>
int(1725)
[62]=>
int(1594)
[33]=>
int(1858)
 }
}
```

Please give me some tips. I will be very pleased.

SOLUTION:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($morning_code as $k=>$subArray){
   arsort($subArray);
   $newArray[$k] = $subArray;
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is a pretty crappy problem description

Comment: do you need to maintain index association?

Comment: it's very good tip with maintain index association like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898822/sort-array-in-php-by-value-and-maintain-index-association

but in my case it sorts by number of results , so after sorting, i got low(12)... high(19)... normal(20) ... where '...' are unsroted results.

Anyway this is all i wanted to help me :) Thank You

Comment: how you want output to be like?

Comment: sorted by (int) values in low,normal and high. like
['low']=>
[33]=>int(233)
[16]=>int(444)
[42]=>int(777) // by int values int(value)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to value sort use below

```
$sortingen = array("normal"=> array(58=>7343,33=>23424,
newArray = Array();

foreach($sortingen as $k=>$subArray){
    sort($subArray);
    newArray[$k] = $subArray;
}
```

if you want to key sort use below

```
$sortingen = array("normal"=> array(58=>7343,33=>23424,
newArray = Array();

foreach($sortingen as $k=>$subArray){
    ksort($subArray);
    newArray[$k] = $subArray;
}
```

Comment: first one is very good, bu it overwrite my keys, after run i got sorted array but i lost my keys ( they were overwited)
array(3) {
  ["normal"]=>
  array(20) {
    [0]=>
    int(413)
    [1]=>
    int(5135)
    [2]=>
    int(5297)
    [3]=>
    int(5322)
    [4]=>
    int(5452)
    [5]=>
    int(6436)
    [6]=>

Comment: i managed it, i changed function from sort to arsort

Comment: use asort  insead of sort

Answer (score 0):

You can use arsort to sort your array.

`<?php arsort(array); ?>`

Comment: i tried all functions under my link , ( laso this one) and with no result