# Sort values within each row of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

My input array is like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 8
        [3] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 1
    )
```

My desired result would be:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [3] => 1
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 8
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [2] => 1
        [1] => 4
        [0] => 7

    )
```

Comment: Refer to [sort array with value and keep key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9898822/6521116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple way with asort

```
array_map(function($v){asort($v); return $v;}, $array);
```

Or you can use uasort()

You can use uasort and array_map to sort the elements. for php7+

```
array_map(function($v){uasort($v, function($a, $b){return $a <=> $b;}); return $v;}, $array);
```

for version<7 use this compare funciton of uasort

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: sorry i dont know what is the variable $a and $b?

Comment: live it unchanged. just set $array with your array

Comment: @Rachmad you can use the first way. just assigin $array of your array, then the output of array_map is you desired result.

Comment: @KrisRoofe, I don't think that one-liners, and particularly ones that do not fit the screen, are a propagation of good style.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php) together with [`asort`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.asort.php):

```
array_walk($array, 'asort');
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/36c6efc60095d0a672d2bf54304b3d0f39b5b138).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arsort` to sort array by values. make a loop and call `asort($arr)` for each sub array you have

Comment: this will result in the inverse way.